Explicit rate of decay of the positive standing wave of the subcritical nonlinear Schrödinger equation
Consider the following semilinear problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
- \Delta u + u = u |u|^{p - 2}
&\text{in} ~ \mathbb{R}^N;
\\
u (x) \to 0 &\text{as} ~ |x| \to \infty,
\end{cases}
$$
where $N \geq 2$, $2 < p < \infty$ if $N = 2$ and $2 < p < \frac{2 N}{N - 
2}$ if $N \geq 3$. It is well-known that there exists $\mu > 0$ such that if $U$ denotes a positive solution to this problem, then
$U (x) |x|^{\frac{N - 1}{2}} e^{|x|} \to \mu$
as $|x| \to \infty$
(see Theorem 2 in Gidas, Ni & Nirenberg's 1981 paper as in Zbl 0469.35052 or MR0634248).
Even though this asymptotic behavior is cited in numerous papers and books, I couldn't find the explicit value (or a numerical estimate) of the positive number $\mu$ with the aforementioned property in the literature, so it isn't clear whether this is not already known or if I simply searched for this information at the wrong places.
I appreciate any help.
